# Calling sqlite3_column_type returns SQLITE_INTEGER for a STRING column that contains only numbers causing an integer overflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm working on a legacy project and have found an issue. The code is reading from an sqlite database. It performs a query and iterates over the statement and then for each column it gets the column name and the column value.

To get the value it calls sqlite3_column_type. Then it checks the types and uses sqlite3_column_int, sqlite3_column_double, sqlite3_column_text, etc. to read the value.

The issue is that there is a row in the DB that has a STRING column but the value contains only numbers (the value was set as 12 characters long, something like @"123456789012"). Calling sqlite3_column_type for this row returns SQLITE_INTEGER as it's only looking at the value of the column and not the declared column type. This means that the code will then read the value with sqlite3_column_int and I'll end up with an integer overflow and a number nothing like the original value contained in the DB.

Here is a quick example:

```
int columnType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, index);

if (columnType == SQLITE_INTEGER) {
    //use sqlite3_column_int(statement, index)
}
else if (columnType == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
    //use sqlite3_column_double(statement, index)
}
else if (columnType == SQLITE_TEXT) {
    //use sqlite3_column_text(statement, index)
}
///etc...
```

How can I make sure the the value I get out from a STRING column containing only numbers is treated correctly? Can I somehow check the declared column type (other than querying and parsing out the original create table sql)? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have set column type "STRING" or "TEXT" ?

Comment: The column type used in the creation of the table is STRING but it seems that the method sqlite3_column_type doesn't actually return this. Instead it just returns the type of the current row's value. Meaning that even for a STRING column it returns SQLITE_INTEGER if the particular value is only numbers.

Comment: Change it to "TEXT" while creating table and check.

Comment: Show the actual table definition.

Comment: Perhaps try https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_decltype.html instead.

Comment: Thanks @topshot that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Using column_decltype instead of column_type means that I get that declared column type (STRING) instead of the type of value. Then I can compare the result against STRING, TEXT, etc.to figure out how to read the value.

Comment: Guess I should have put it as an answer instead though I wasn't certain it would solve your need. ;)

Comment: Using of column `sqlite3_column_decltype` didn't worked for me perfectly. It returns `null` on this query: `SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='test_table';` after insert to `test_table`. While result value is number: `25` in my case. And it must return `TEXT` instead of `null`.